# cannot install wls1034_linux32.bin

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, installation, soa

i am beginning to install soa Suite and oracle 10g express edition in my ubuntu system.
for this i am referring to quickstartsoasuite11g... .pdf guide.
As per the steps given in this guide, i installed oracle, but when i am trying to install wls1034_linux32.bin file, i get the following error on the terminal:

```
 [/root/stageFMW/wls1034_linux32.bin]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.
** Error during init, error code = 2.
```

where am i getting wrong? how do i solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not include Ubuntu in its list of supported Linux flavours.  Basically it only certifies against "enterprise grade" distros such as RHEL, Suse and inevitably Oracle Enterprise Linux.

Almost certainly SOA Suite and Oracle XE *will* run on Ubuntu but you will need to tweak some stuff and/or download additional libraries.  This is not a task for somebody who isn't familiar with the Oracle product set.

If you have a fairly beefy system you should consider running a virtualised environment.  Oracle offers [a VirtualBox install which will run on Ubuntu](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).  You can then run [the pre-built SOA Suite appliance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/learnmore/vmsoa-172279.html).

(If you don't have a beefy system you're going to struggle with SOA Suite: running web servers, databases and JDeveloper sucks up a lot of compute power.)

Answer (score 0):

I got that same error when I tried to install Jdevloper using root (super user). I corrected it by installing with a different user.